# Combobox doesn't display selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

in code:

```
private ObservableCollection<State> allStates = new ObservableCollection<State>();
```

//State is a class with many properties, one of them is int 'Index' and int 'OneArrow'

```
public MainWindow()
{
...

this.MyComboBox.ItemsSource = allStates;
this.MyComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Index";
this.MyComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "Index";

this.DataContext = MyState;
}
```

in xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="MyComboBox" 
Width="60" Height="20" 
IsEnabled="False" 
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=OneArrow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

binding is working, it's fine, but I have another problem.
Combobox doesn't dsiplay selected item. I mean in a drop-down list a right item is highlighted, but when drop-down list is hidden, nothing is diplayed.

[image]

Comment: Could you paste up you State class, is "Index" part of State and is "OneArrow" the same datatype as "Index"

Comment: public int OneArrow
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(OneArrowProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OneArrowProperty, value); }
        }


        public int Index {
            get
            {
                return index;
            }
            set
            {
                index = value;
                this.IndexTextBlock.Text = "q" + value.ToString();
            }
        }

Comment: both OneArrow and Index are int

Comment: Are you setting the ItemsSource to a collection of State and trying to select an int? It does not have any sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all you classes its hard to guess whats going wrong.
Here is my interprtation on what your code looks like.

Xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Grid >
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=AllStates}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Index"
                  SelectedValuePath="Index"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=OneArrow}"
                  Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,82,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AllStates.Add(new State { Index = 1 });
            AllStates.Add(new State { Index = 2 });
            AllStates.Add(new State { Index = 3 });
            AllStates.Add(new State { Index = 4 });
        }

        private ObservableCollection<State> allStates = new ObservableCollection<State>();
        public ObservableCollection<State> AllStates 
        {
            get { return allStates; }
            set { allStates = value; }
        }

        private int oneArrow;
        public int OneArrow
        {
            get { return oneArrow; }
            set { oneArrow = value; }
        }

    }

    public class State : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int index;
        public int Index
        {
            get { return index; }
            set { index = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Index"); }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
```

This seems to work ok, but like I said I have no idea what your State class looks like or where OneArrow is located (mainform or State)